# Matrix inverse of the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I know that for any given matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ the following matrix
$$ B = cI_3 + dU^TU $$ is invertible, where $I_3$ is the three by three identity matrix and $c,d>0$ are constants coming from the modelled physical system. Precisely, in my case I have that $U=ST$ where $S,T\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ are both skew-symmetric matrices.
I even know that if the matrix $U^TU$ has rank 1, then there is an iterative way to compute this inverse.

Is there some reference or some formula I can see which applies to explicit the inversion of the matrix $B$? If it may help, I know that the matrix $U$ has rank 2 and it is singular.

Comment: What if $c=d=0$?

Comment: Of course it does not work, it is even enough to have $c=0$ in my case to have problems, but I know explicitly $c$ and $d$ in my case and they are different from zero

Comment: Your first sentence seems to state that $B$ is invertible for any $U$, $b$ and $c$, which is false.  If you could let us know all of the available hypothesis, such as the explicit values of $c$ and $d$, perhaps it would be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Now it should be better.

Comment: Since you are working in a pretty low dimension, it shouldn't be very costly to invert your matrix by any one of the usual methods of
linear algebra.  In higher dimensions I would write the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{c+dx}$$ as the uniform limit of a
sequence $\{p_n\}_n$ of polynomials on some sufficiently large interval $[0,b]$ and then $p_n(B)$ will converge to
$B^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok so you do not suggest to use a particular formula but to proceed with direct computations, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it may help someone, I have inverted it with the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, since the eigenvalues in my case are pretty easy to compute.

So, I get an expression similar to this one
$$ B^{-1} = c_1B^2 + c_2B + c_3I_3 $$
which is something quite simple to study.